# Can we change the design of the Tor site during beta phase?

Tags: feature-request

is there any way we can change the design of the site and add graphics during the current phase?

And if the feature is not available yet, can we request it early?

I know it usually takes a year or so to get to that part, but we could use some graphics to educate users about some privacy concerns while using the site. Just to stay on the safe side.

Answer (score 3):

If by "graphics" you mean the full site design, unfortunately we can't request that early. SE employs its own graphics designers who work on things like that, and they don't let them out of the shed until they know a site is going to be sticking around.

If you'd like to start discussing what the site design might look like though, this is the place to do it! For examples, see these [two](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1343/how-do-i-propose-artwork-for-this-site-once-it-gets-gradu-mated) [questions](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1705/design-concept-for-christianity-se) on Christianity.SE or [this one](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/638/site-design-ideas-updated-with-mockup) on TeX.SE.

I'm not sure how the site design could be used to educate users about privacy concerns, but if you want to put a few educational graphics like that somewhere, feel free to make a meta question with all the graphics you want! This is probably the best way to educate users about privacy concerns. Then we can make it a part of the FAQ, or possibly feature it (so it will show up in the sidebar on the main site), etc.